# RegEx remove trailing period

Tags: regex

I am trying to filter url's. My object here is to catch any url in a document.

Here are my examples that I am searching for

```
example.org
www.example.org
example.org/some/end/string
example.org/?someendsctringSOow?2332q3=sda33ad
www.example.org/some/end/string
example1.example.org/?someendsctringSOow?2332q3=sda33ad
https://example34.domain.org/?someendsctringSOow?2332q3=sda33ad
```

There are more examples that I have, (20) total. Essentially every format of a url that you can think of. I had to restrict it down to less than 8 because of my reputation level.

Strip any remaining period at the end of the url.

Using the following RegEX I can get most of it work. However, it keeps grabbing the periods at the end.

```
(https?:\/\/)?([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256})?\.([a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6})(\b[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/g
```

I have everything working but the remaining (.)

I have tried !?=. !?=[.] !?=(.)[.]

I need another set of eyes, aka smarter person than I, to help me out.

Thank you in advanced for the help!

Comment: Show us expected output please

Comment: @GillesQuénot Sorry, I can't it wont allow me to and any further url's

Comment: @GillesQuénot - the out put needs to find the complete url. this is the very end goal. I am using php to read PDF's and scan for these url's. The the output would be the full url in the document.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly the problem is, running your regex over your examples doesn't select any trailing period. Show more specific details of what exactly is wrong and what exactly you want instead.

Comment: @Blindy what's not clear? I don't know how much more I can say, getting the full URL. I can only put so many url's in the here to get my point across which also says I cannot put anymore url's to show what the expect output is going to be.

Comment: Well unless you figure out how to give technical details in your question, my best guess is that you're parsing the regex result wrong and are adding trailing periods where there aren't any. Do with that as you will.

Comment: @Blindy well that was obtuse...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding the regexr domain, I was able to build out a regex method that worked.

```
(https?:\/\/|HTTPS?:\/\/)?([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256})?\.([a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,})(\b[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+~#?&//=]*)?/g
```

[Link showing the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2FfY.png)

Answer (score 0):

`(https?:\/\/)?([-\w\d@:%._\+~#=]{1,256})?\.([\w\d()]{1,6})(\b[^.][-\w\d()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*?)?(\.*(?:\b|\B))`
https://regex101.com/r/gK2ZxJ/1

I added `(\.*(?:\b|\B))` to the end to match trailing periods. Then set the URL path pattern to lazy match to match as few characters as possible: `(\b[^.][-\w\d()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*?)`

But lazy matching was still selecting a trailing period if it was the first character in the path so I added `[^.]` to the start. `\w` and `\d` are allowed in character groups so I replaced those too.

This returns the periods as a match but you can ignore that group or if you are doing a replacement you can append the period group to the end.

Comment: Thank you for this. I just tested it. It still is pulling the period at the end and now it's no longer getting the full url. it just get the domain.

Comment: @JoesMomma I would need more examples to see why, but hopefully this example gives some ideas.

Comment: my original example works. However, it just leaves the trailing period. It gets the entire url. I am trying to keep the code efficient as possible. The regex loads the regex to a variable that is an array.

Comment: @JoesMomma I would recommend finding someone elses code online since URLs are quite complex to parse, especially with regex.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. However, If I copy someone else's code I am not learning. Asking for a trophy and not really participating. I want to learn what it is I am doing wrong here.

Comment: `((https?:\/\/)?([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256})?\.([a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,})(\b[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?)/g` This is a lot closer. It makes a mast group for the string. but when I try `*(?=.\s)` it's just removing the last character.